# Комаринская

Tags: этимология

А почему танец называется "Комаринская"? При чем тут комары?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Танец вообще-то называется "Камаринская".  Хотя исторически написание через "О" как раз более аргументировано.

Под "комаринским мужиком" понимали бродягу, пьяницу, полууголовный элемент. Название связано, видимо, с "Комарицкой (Комаринской) волостью" (существовавшей в XVII-XVIII веках на территории современной Брянской области), как раз и славившейся лихими людишками. Но и это название не связано с комарами.

Вот версии, приводимые Вики:

*Существуют различные версии происхождения названия Комарицкой волости:*

*1) от реки Марицы, при которой стоит город Севск. Однако Марица — относительно небольшая река, её географическая значимость не настолько существенна, чтобы дать название столь обширной волости.*

*2) от позднелат. commarca - «граница, предел» (см. «комарка»). Действительно, в течение долгого времени Комарицкая волость оставалась для Московского государства пограничной, да и латинское происхождение названия вполне объяснимо, поскольку оно возникло во времена польско-литовского владычества.*

*3) Г. М. Пясецкий предполагает происхождение названия Комарицкой волости от слова "комара", или "камера", что означает государственную казну польско-литовских королей, которые до конца XV века владели Комарицкой волостью как своим личным имением. Московские государи, отвоевав эту волость в начале XVI века, также содержали её в своем Дворцовом (Камерарном) ведомстве, а Лжедмитрий II в жалованной грамоте своему мнимому тестю, сандомирскому воеводе Юрию Мнишеку, писанной на польском языке, называет Севск Камарском.*

*4) Т. А. Мартемьянов, первый исследователь плясовой песни «Камаринская», считает, что это название происходит от слова «каморник» — так называли людей, не имевших своих домов и живших в чужих избах и каморах. К их числу относили сторожей, истопников, работников в доме, занимавших каморки. Комарицкая волость, вследствие усиленной колонизации по укреплению южных границ Московского государства, была краем бездомников, бродяг. Волость, по мнению Мартемьянова, «кишела каморниками, и им, вероятно, она обязана своим названием».*

По большому счету все версии весьма сомнительные, но если выбирать "из четырёх зол", то я бы выбрал скорее третью, как наиболее основательную.